# customize UITableView Header Section at run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have set header back ground using the code below but I want to change the color of header back again on run time when I click on the button that is added as a subview on the header.
please provide me code, thanks in advance :)

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    header = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _tableView.bounds.size.width, 50)];
 header.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"homeCellHeaderBackGround.png"]];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30)];
    label.text = _array[section][@"name"];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    [header addSubview:label];


    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 10, 70, 35)];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onExpandButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //[button setTitle:@"Expand" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTag:section];

    [header addSubview:button];

    return header;
}
```

Comment: Please check this link. may be what you need is here.
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621389/how-can-i-catch-touch-events-to-a-uitableview-section-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the background color of the section header by following code:

```
- (IBAction)onExpandButton:(id)sender {
   UIView *header = ((UIButton *)sender).superView;
   header.backgroundColor = <Whatever UIColor you like>;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify it in run time by:

**first:**

you can declare a global variable/propery like:

```
@property (nonatomic) UIView *tableHeader;
```

and set it under `-(void)viewDidLoad`

like

`self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.tableHeader;`

or using the delagate:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return self.tableHeader;
}
```

and modify it anywhere you like, but dont forget to reload you table section header, probably `[tableView reloadSections:NSIndexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation];` will do.

**But**

In your case you can retreive/get the tableHeader made inside the delegate:

`-(UIView *)tableView:tableView viewForHeaderInSection:section`

by

```
UIView *tableHeaderView = [self tableView:yourTableView viewForHeaderInSection:yourSection];
```

then modify `tableHeaderView`..

or simply reassign tableHeader by:

```
yourTableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView;
```

your by using `header` alone, since as i can see it's a global variable..
change/update it directly like:

```
header.backgroundColor = [UIColor yourNewColor];
```

hope i've helped you.. happy coding, cheers..

Comment: all these information is really helpful may be I can make it useful in another scenarios but kslcam's answer just worked perfectly this time. but still i wanted to appreciate your detailed handful information thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)onExpandButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIView *tmpView = [self.YourTableViewName headerViewForSection:sender.tag];
    tmpView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"homeCellHeaderBackGround.png"]];
}
```

-You got the view from your table view header for section method. After you can set your image view on view.

Comment: sorry it is not working may be sender is a button i think it is not connecting to its super view but using superView.sender is working fine with same logic. see aboce kslcam answer which is working perfectly according to my requirement :)